# What is Heel of Round?

Tags: beef

The Us cuts of beef are very different from the cuts of beef in my country (the Netherlands). In the famous book "The French Menu cookbook" Richard Olney talks about the Heel of Round and the Bottom Round. Could anyone explain those sub-primal cuts or maybe say how you can translate those cuts to British cuts or French cuts of beef ? Olney uses these cuts of beef for preparing pot-au-feu ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between French and British cuts of beef?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34597/what-is-the-difference-between-french-and-british-cuts-of-beef)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Beef Heel of Round represents a cut from the beef round immediately above the hock. This roast is composed of many small muscle groups, has a lot of seam fat, and is one of the least tender cuts of beef.

Braising for long periods of time works best for that cut.

Bottom round is rump roast and the top part furthest away from the hock.

Source: https://animalscience.unl.edu/beef-meat-identification

Comment: The bulk of your answer is copied. Please include the appropriate citation.

Comment: But is the Heel of Round different from the Shank ??

Comment: @OldMan shank are the front legs, these are the hind legs :)